# Finding all pairs of integers that satisfy a bilinear Diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratics

The problem asks to "find all pairs of integers $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation $xy - 2x + 7y = 49$.

So far, I've got

\begin{align}
xy - 2x + 7y &= 49 \\
x\left(y - 2\right) + 7 &= 49
\\
y &\leq 49
\end{align}

I can't get any further. Any help?

Comment: You might like to recast as $xy-2x+7y-14=35$

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: $xy+7y = 2x+49 \implies (x+7)y = 2x+49 \implies y = \dfrac{2x+49}{x+7}= 2 + \dfrac{35}{x+7}\implies (x+7) \mid 35\implies x+7 = \pm 1, \pm 5, \pm 7, \pm 35$

Comment: How do you go from y = (2x + 49)/(x + 7) to 2 + 35/(x + 7) ?

Comment: @Izal $$\dfrac{2x+49}{x+7} = \dfrac{(2x+14)+35}{x+7} = \dfrac{2(x+7)+35}{x+7} = 2 + \dfrac{35}{x+7}$$